# Proving $T$ and $U$ are equal if I know $(X,T)$ and $(X,U)$ are hausdorff and compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

This question is from Wayne Patty Exercise 4.2

> Let $T$ and $U$ are Topologies on set X. Suppose $ (X,T) $ and $(X,U)$ are compact Haurdsorff Spaces. Prove that $T=U$ or $T$ is not a subset of $U$ or $U$ is not a subset of T.

I thought of proving it by this way: Assuming that if $T$ is a subset of $U$ or $U$ is a subset of $ T$ then $T=U$ must be true.
But I was unable to think on how to use compactness or hausdorff property and was unable to proceed.

Well, also this question was asked before on this website. But I am unable to understand how the solution will work despite trying to understand it for a fair amount of time as it was just outlined.

So, I am looking for a detailed solution.

Comment: You should try to follow those outlines by yourself. Consider the identity map on $X$. When will it be continuous? When will it map closed sets to closed sets?

Comment: Hint: the continuous image of a compact set is compact. Also, if $f$ is a bijection, then the preimage of a set under  $f^{-1}$ is actually the image of that set under $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The continuous image of a compact space is a compact space.
2. A  subset of a compact Hausdorff space is closed iff it is compact.

Suppose $T\subseteq U.$

Then the function $f=id_X$ is  continuous from $(X,U)$ to $(X,T)$ because if $S$ is $T$-open then $S\in T$ so $S\in U$ so $f^{-1}S=S$ is $U$-open.

Consider any $Y\in U.$

Then $X$ \ $Y$ is $U$-closed,

so by 2., $X$ \ $Y$ is compact in $(X,U),$

so by 1., its image $f[X$ \ $Y]=X$ \ $Y$ is compact in $(X,T),$

so by 2., $X$  \ $Y $ is $T$-closed,

so $Y\in T.$

In summary, $T\subseteq U\implies \forall Y\,(Y\in U\implies Y\in T)\implies U\subseteq T.$

Comment: Note that we use both the "if"  and the "only if" of 2.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the fact that a continuous bijection $f: A \rightarrow B$ where the domain $A$ is compact Hausdorff and the codomain $B$ is hausdorff is a homeomorphism.

If you take the finer topology in the domain and the coarser on the codomain, the identity function is the continuous bijection we need. That is take $$i: (X, \tau_1) \rightarrow (X,\tau_2)$$ with $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$. Thus the identity a homeomorphism, from which you conclude that, if comparable, the two topologies are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathscr{T}\subsetneqq\mathscr{U}$, and let $U\in\mathscr{U}\setminus\mathscr{T}$. Let $K=X\setminus U$; $K$ is not closed in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$, but $K$ **is** closed in $\langle X,\mathscr{U}\rangle$, which is a compact space, so $K$ is compact in $\langle X,\mathscr{U}\rangle$: every cover of $K$ by $\mathscr{U}$-open sets has a finite subcover.

Let $\mathscr{V}$ be a cover of $K$ by $\mathscr{T}$-open sets. (I.e., $K\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{V}$, and $\mathscr{V}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$.) $\mathscr{T}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$, so $\mathscr{V}$ is automatically also a $\mathscr{U}$-open cover of $K$, and as such it has a finite subcover $\mathscr{V}_0$. Thus, every cover of $K$ by $\mathscr{T}$-open sets has a finite subcover, and $K$ is therefore compact in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$. But every compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed, and $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$ is Hausdorff, so $K$ is closed in $\langle X,\mathscr{T}\rangle$. This contradiction shows that $\mathscr{T}$ cannot be a proper subset of $\mathscr{U}$.

The same argument, with the rôles of $\mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{U}$ reversed, shows that $\mathscr{U}$ cannot be a proper subset of $\mathscr{T}$. Thus, either $\mathscr{T}=\mathscr{U}$, or $\mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{U}$ are not related by inclusion at all.